# Load Runner facing isse during Dyanmic data handling

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am using load runner 9.5. I am facing a problem during Dyanmic data handling. Scenario is given below-

I have Library management application. Login-> Select book(data display based on User credential) -->Purchage and Logout.

Ex: Guest user: 50 Books display to choose
    Admin : All Books display choose
    Normal user : 100 Bokks display choose

Please help me How to handle these type of dynamic data based on user role. Is there need to create different script with different role ?

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow the below steps** -

1. Record the same flow with the same user credential  2 times (*Replica of first script*)
2. Compare the scripts using W diff
3. Find the values which are different like purchase order, timestamp and user session.
4. Correlate the values which are highlighted in yellow means value which is different in each script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had the benefit of training in LoadRunner and a mentor for your first year of work in this field?